# How to declare Ref variable when passing parameters in VB.net as we do in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

in C# I can do something like this:

```
return int.TryParse(someStr, out int value) ? value : 0;
```

but in VB.Net

```
return if(Integer.TryParse(someStr, ByRef value as Integer), value, 0)
```

I receive error in `ByRef`.
I know that I can do it like:

```
Dim value as Integer = 0
Integer.TryParse(someStr, value)
Return value
```

but I was wondering if there is a way to do it in one line as we do it in C#.

Comment: I suspect that there is any recent development in VB.net in this area.

Comment: VB syntax is no longer being extended - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-support-planned-for-net-5-0/